# SAP HANA SQL - start week at Sunday? WEEK() starts Monday by default

Tags: sql, hana

Business needs the week to start at Sunday but the SAP HANA SQL WEEK() starts on Monday. How do I start the calendar week at Sunday? I have found a few web pages indicating this as a problem such as [this one](https://answers.sap.com/questions/125185/how-to-use-week-function-in-hana-but-with-differen.html), but no solution.

CALWEEK here is already in the table so I would focus on CALWEEK_DERIVED.
[image: Image shows Calendar week changes on Monday March 9, 2020 instead of Sunday March 8, 2020]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here a shorter variant considering corner case at year begin without requiring a helper table:

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION week_sunday(DATE date) RETURNS ret integer AS BEGIN 
    ret = CASE weekday(extract(YEAR FROM date)||'-01-01')
          WHEN 6 THEN
            CASE weekday(date)
            WHEN 6 THEN week(date)
            ELSE week(date)-1
            END
          ELSE
            CASE weekday(date)
            WHEN 6 THEN week(date)+1
            ELSE week(date)
            END
        END;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked. Note that the derived Sunday-starting week is **CALWEEK** and other columns are present to assist with validation.

This solution requires the presence of "_SYS_BI"."M_TIME_DIMENSION", which may have to be generated per the comment at the bottom of this [website](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12126765/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-week-of-quarter-in-a-d.html).

I include special handling when the year starts on a Sunday like in 2017 - look for `WEEKDAY(TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap),'-01-01'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) = 6`

I will examine below:

- The present year 2020
- *Edge case 1*: When the year starts on a Sunday
- *Edge case 2*: When the year starts on a Saturday
- Validation SQL examining from year 1900 - 2100

## The present year 2020

```
-- Current year 2020 started on a Wednesday      
select date_sap, YEAR(date_sap) as year_date_sap, WEEKDAY(date_sap) as weekday_date_sap, WEEK(date_sap) as SAPWEEK,
(CASE     
    -- subtract by 1 when year starts on a Sunday like in 2017
    when WEEKDAY(TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap),'-01-01'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) = 6 and
     ((YEAR(ADD_DAYS(date_sap, 1)) = (YEAR(date_sap) + 1)) and (WEEKDAY(date_sap) != 6)) THEN CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap), WEEK(date_sap) - 1)
    when WEEKDAY(TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap),'-01-01'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) = 6 and
     ((YEAR(ADD_DAYS(date_sap, 1)) = (YEAR(date_sap) + 1)) and (WEEKDAY(date_sap) = 6)) THEN CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap), WEEK(date_sap))
    when WEEKDAY(TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap),'-01-01'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) = 6 and
     YEAR(ADD_DAYS(date_sap, 1)) = (YEAR(date_sap)) THEN CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap), WEEK(ADD_DAYS(date_sap, 1)) - 1)
    when ((YEAR(ADD_DAYS(date_sap, 1)) = (YEAR(date_sap) + 1)) and (WEEKDAY(date_sap) != 6)) THEN CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap), WEEK(date_sap))
    when ((YEAR(ADD_DAYS(date_sap, 1)) = (YEAR(date_sap) + 1)) and (WEEKDAY(date_sap) = 6)) THEN CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap), WEEK(date_sap) + 1)
    when YEAR(ADD_DAYS(date_sap, 1)) = (YEAR(date_sap)) THEN CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap), WEEK(ADD_DAYS(date_sap, 1)))
END) AS CALWEEK
from "_SYS_BI"."M_TIME_DIMENSION" 
-- to eliminate missing values (appears as "?")
where date_sap >= TO_DATE('2019-12-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
      and date_sap <= TO_DATE('2020-01-14', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
      order by date_sap;
```

[image: Shows CALWEEK increments in 2020 on Sunday, January 5th]

## *Edge case 1*: When the year starts on a Saturday

### Year 2011

```
-- Same SQL but use:
where date_sap >= TO_DATE('2010-12-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
      and date_sap <= TO_DATE('2011-01-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

[image: Year 2011 - CALWEEK increments on January 1st then Sundays: January 2nd and 9th]

## *Edge case 2*: When the year starts on a Sunday

### Year 2017

```
-- Same SQL but use:
where date_sap >= TO_DATE('2016-12-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
      and date_sap <= TO_DATE('2017-01-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

[image: Year 2017 - CALWEEK increments on January 1st and the next Sunday: January 8th]

## Validation SQL examining from year 1900 - 2100

### need the ability to create a temporary table

```
-- need the ability to create a temporary table
drop table #CALWEEK_TEST;

create local temporary table #CALWEEK_TEST as (
select date_sap, YEAR(date_sap) as year_date_sap, WEEKDAY(date_sap) as weekday_date_sap, WEEK(date_sap) as SAPWEEK,
(CASE     
    -- subtract by 1 when week starts on a Sunday like in 2017
    when WEEKDAY(TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap),'-01-01'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) = 6 and
     ((YEAR(ADD_DAYS(date_sap, 1)) = (YEAR(date_sap) + 1)) and (WEEKDAY(date_sap) != 6)) THEN CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap), WEEK(date_sap) - 1)
    when WEEKDAY(TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap),'-01-01'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) = 6 and
     ((YEAR(ADD_DAYS(date_sap, 1)) = (YEAR(date_sap) + 1)) and (WEEKDAY(date_sap) = 6)) THEN CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap), WEEK(date_sap))
    when WEEKDAY(TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap),'-01-01'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) = 6 and
     YEAR(ADD_DAYS(date_sap, 1)) = (YEAR(date_sap)) THEN CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap), WEEK(ADD_DAYS(date_sap, 1)) - 1)
    when ((YEAR(ADD_DAYS(date_sap, 1)) = (YEAR(date_sap) + 1)) and (WEEKDAY(date_sap) != 6)) THEN CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap), WEEK(date_sap))
    when ((YEAR(ADD_DAYS(date_sap, 1)) = (YEAR(date_sap) + 1)) and (WEEKDAY(date_sap) = 6)) THEN CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap), WEEK(date_sap) + 1)
    when YEAR(ADD_DAYS(date_sap, 1)) = (YEAR(date_sap)) THEN CONCAT(YEAR(date_sap), WEEK(ADD_DAYS(date_sap, 1)))
END) AS CALWEEK
from "_SYS_BI"."M_TIME_DIMENSION" 
-- to eliminate missing values (appears as "?")
  where date_sap >= TO_DATE('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
      and date_sap <= TO_DATE('2100-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
      order by date_sap
);
```

-- Check if number of records is always 1 - 7 per CALWEEK => SUCCESS

```
select distinct count(*) as RECORDS_PER_CALWEEK from #CALWEEK_TEST
group by CALWEEK;
```

-- Check if any unusual CALWEEK values (expect 1 - 53) => SUCCESS

```
select distinct SUBSTRING(CALWEEK, 5) as WEEKONLY from #CALWEEK_TEST
order by WEEKONLY;
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION non_iso_week(in_date DATE)
RETURNS week INTEGER LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT AS BEGIN
  week := CASE EXTRACT(DOW FROM in_date)
            WHEN 0 THEN WEEK(in_date) +1
            ELSE WEEK(in_date)
          END;
END;
```

Then:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  calweek
, non_iso_week(order_date) AS calweek_derived
, order_date
FROM dummy
WHERE order_date >='2020-03-07'
  AND order_date <='2020-03-10'
;
```

Comment: The function creating code failed with SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "RETURN": line 2 col 1 (at pos 59).

Comment: double-checked the SAP HANA function creation syntax - and modified accordingly

Comment: I do not think this will work in 2011 if you compare January 1 (Saturday) to January 2 (Sunday). Can you check?

Comment: The current function creation code returns an error for me: SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "DOW": line 3 col 24 (at pos 129)

Comment: should be `WEEKDAY(date)` instead of `EXTRACT(DOW FROM date)` but this solution does not consider corner case at year begin/end